# Web API Missing on deployment

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

So I have a C# MVC Web API and Web Application that is an all-in-one project. I've created something similar to this in the past but the Web Application and Web API were two different projects with two different URLs.

For example:

The Web Application would be hosted at `mywebsite.com/webapp`

The Web API would be hosted at `mywebsite.com/webapi`

Any time I wanted to call the Web API from the Web Application all I had to do is send an Ajax request using the URL `mywebsite.com/webapi/api/getdata`

However, with my current project it's all-in-one. So in testing I would simply call `/api/getdata` and it would work just fine in Visual Studio debug. But when I deploy this site for testing and actually host it all my API calls are met with HTTP 404 errors.

So how do I call the Web API when the Web API doesn't have it's own distinct URL?

Comment: How are you generating the urls in your ajax calls?

Comment: In testing it's this: 

xmlhttp.open("GET",  '/api/Users/GetUser?Username=' + username, false);

Comment: Are you hosting it in a folder? Or the root for your domain name?

Comment: It's in a folder. That's what I was missing. I set it to call /ProjectFolder/api/Users/GetUser and it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

In IIS I converted the folder to an application and then made sure to switch the calls from

```
mywebsite.com/api/getdata
```

to

```
mywebsite.com/myproject/api/getdata
```

and it's working now.

Credit to @mxmissile for pointing it out.